# Network and attributes (nodes - neighbors)

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

In this example, a network from a dataframe df has 4 nodes and 5 links:

```
N      T      P
1      2      B
1      3      B
2      1      A
2      3      A
2      4      A
3      1      B
3      2      B
3      4      B
4      2      A
4      3      A
```

The nodes have the following properties (summary):

```
N       P
1       B
2       A
3       B
4       A
```

For each node, I'd need to calculate the proportion of neighbors of the same type.
Building the network by joining the two dataframes, if I select nodes with `P=A`, Iàd have:

```
N    F1
1   1/2 # node 1 has only one node having P=A
2   1/3 # node 2 has 1 node with P=A and two with P=B
3   1/3
4   1/2
```

Once I have this list, I'd need for each node either the list of mean of the values found above of the node's `P=A` neighbors.

This mean

```
N   F2
1   1/3
2   1/2
3   1/2, 1/3
4   1/3
```

Code for building the network

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='N', target='T')
colors = []
for node in G:
    if node in df["P"].values:
        colors.append("lightblue")
    else: colors.append("lightgreen")

nx.draw(G, 
        node_color=colors,
        with_labels=True)
```

I don't know how to check node's neighbors and calculate the probability that they have  the same P, so how to get the expected outputs F1 and F2. I think the problem is on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting `F1` is pretty straightforward. For each unique node attribute value, induce a subgraph, count the edges, divide by the overall degree of the node.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Compute homophily score by node.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


if __name__ == '__main__':

    edges = [
        (1,      2),
        (1,      3),
        (2,      1),
        (2,      3),
        (2,      4),
        (3,      1),
        (3,      2),
        (3,      4),
        (4,      2),
        (4,      3),
    ]

    nodes = [
        (1, {'property'  :    'B'}),
        (2, {'property'  :    'A'}),
        (3, {'property'  :    'B'}),
        (4, {'property'  :    'A'}),
    ]

    g = nx.Graph()
    g.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    g.add_edges_from(edges)

    neighbours_of_same_type = dict()
    for letter in 'AB':
        nodes_with_property = [node for node, data in g.nodes(data=True) if data['property'] == letter]
        h = g.subgraph(nodes_with_property)
        neighbours_of_same_type.update(h.degree)

    degree = dict(g.degree)
    output = dict()
    for node, _ in nodes:
        output[node] = neighbours_of_same_type[node] / degree[node]

    print(output)
    # {1: 0.5, 2: 0.3333333333333333, 3: 0.3333333333333333, 4: 0.5}
```

> Once I have this list, I'd need for each node either the list of mean of the values found above of the node's P=A neighbors.

Your definition of `F2` makes little sense to me but I suspect that it can be readily computed from F1?

Comment: Hi Paul Brodersen, thank you for your answer. In `F2`, I am trying to look at the values of node's `P=A` neighbors. For example, node three has two neighbors with `P=A`, having `1/2` and `1/3` respectively. Node `1` has only neighbor with that property, having value `1/2`. I hope this can help.